# Why wrap a DOM element in jQuery if doesn't simplify things? (Example from jQuery Cookbook)

Tags: jquery

I came across this example in the O'Reilly *jQuery Cookbook* (recipe 3.1):

```
var urls = [];
$("div#post a[href]").each(function(i){
    urls[i] = $(this).attr('href');
});
alert(urls.join(","));
```

I understand that `$().each(fn)` runs the function in the context of the DOM element selected.  What I don't understand is: **Why wrap the DOM element in a jQuery object?**

It seems to me like `urls[i] = this.href;` would have been the more straightforward approach here.

- Is it a best practice to always wrap
  DOM elements in jQuery before
  touching them?
- Or is the author doing
  this simply to show us that it can be
  done?
- Or is it done for some other
  reason altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of jQuery's primary goals is to act as a consistent layer between the programmer and the potentially unpredictable browser-defined functions. So yes, it is generally best practice to use the jQuery wrappings to any DOM functions.

Comment: If you look through the un-min version of jquery you will see under .attr (for setting attr's mind) that Blackberry's seem to be problematic, tabindex gives odd results and it tries to normalize and that IE requires the values to be strings etc... It is just good practice to have that safety net - just in case.

Comment: Great point.  I spent about half an hour today tinkering with a layout detail that worked fine on Chrome, but not on IE.  It wasn't JavaScript-related, but the more of those types of problems I can avoid the better.  Why should I have to remember that the setting attributes is cross-browser-safe when I have something like `$().attr()`?

Answer (score 1):

Typically I try to do all JavaScript in native JavaScript and use jQuery where appropriate. That being said, if you don't wrap the DOM element in the jQuery object then you won't be able to access the jQuery methods.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping with jQuery Object allows for chaining with other jQuery functions. jQuery main purpose is to achieve cross browser compatibility. It also simplifies the way we work with  JavaScript.

Ex: 
`$('#id').attr(...).css(...).delay().fadeIn().fadeOut().remove()`.... and so on. It would take many lines of code, time and effort to write this with plain Javascript, and not to mention maintaining browser compatibility.